# Router Outlet displays more than 1 component

Tags: html, routes, angular-cli

I am having trouble seting up the navigation of my app. For some reason the router outlet i have set keeps displaying the components even after clicking a routerlink to another component, it just show them on after the other and if i keep clicking de links the tables(thats what my components are) just are displayed one more time on the view.

That's my sidenav:

```
<ul id="sideNav"  class="side-nav">
  <li>
<div class="square " id="logoContainer">
  <img src="../../assets/img/{{brand}}Logo.jpg" id="logo" class="backImg">
</div>
</li>
<li><a routerLink="/admRegiones">Inicio<i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
</li>
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
<li>
  <a class="collapsible-header">Regiones<i class="material-icons" style="padding-left: 15px">terrain</i></a>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/admRegiones" class="waves-effect waves-blue"><i class="material-icons right" style="padding-left: 10px">add_location</i>  Administrar regiones  </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
<li class="no-padding">
<ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="collapsible-header">Locaciones<i class="material-icons" style="padding-left: 15px">map</i></a>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/buscarLocacion"  class="waves-effect waves-blue"><i class="material-icons right" style="padding-left: 10px">location_searching</i>Ir a locación </a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/admLocaciones"  class="waves-effect waves-blue"><i class="material-icons right" style="padding-left: 10px">add_location</i>  Administrar locaciones  </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This my routes:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'admLocaciones',
    component: AdmLocacionesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'buscarLocacion',
    component: BuscarLocacionComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admRegiones',
    component: AdmRegionesComponent
  }
])
```

Here my component to display(both admRegiones and admLocaciones are practically the same):

```
<div class="container col s8"style="padding-top: 4%;">
<a href="#modalNuevaLocacion" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (click)="openModal(); exportedInitialize();">Modal</a>  <table class="highlight striped center" id="tablaLocaciones" onload="loadTablaLocaciones()">
<hr>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Región</th>
  <th>Editar</th>
  <th>Eliminar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="locacionesBody">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and this my app-component template:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div id="body">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-locacion></app-locacion>
<app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
```